# Length of cycle must be at least order of longest path

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph with distinct vertices $x$ and $y$, and suppose $P$, $Q$ are $a-b$ paths in $G$ s.t. $P \neq Q$ and $V(P) \cap V(Q) = \{x,y\}$. Show that $G$ contains a cycle of length at least $P$.

Disclaimer: This is a homework assignment for an intro to graph theory course, however I'm trying to get a better understanding of the question.

Clearly $G$ contains a cycle because the subgraph induced by $P$ and $Q$ is a closed circuit, and one of $P$ or $Q$ must have order greater than 3 otherwise $P=Q$ which contradicts our assumption ($|P|=|Q|=2 \implies P = Q$ specifically in this case). Because $P$ and $Q$ do not share any vertices, the paths $P$ and $Q$ must induce a subgraph that is a cycle in this case.

I'm struggling to understand why the cycle length $n\geq |P|$. Intuitively, suppose $V(Q) = \{x,y\}$, that is to say $x$ and $y$ are adjacent and $Q$ is simply the edge between $x$ and $y$, then in this case wouldn't the cycle length $n\geq |P|+1$? If $P$ is the alternate longer $x-y$ path, then to close the path wouldn't we need an additional traversal from $y$ to $x$, demonstrating $n\geq |P|+1$?

Sorry if I've made any errors in my terminology, I am relatively new to the field of Graph Theory.

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$? Are they the same as $x$ and $y$? And if you can show that $n \ge |P|+1$, doesn't that prove that $n \ge |P|$ as well?

Comment: @MishaLavrov Ah sorry. That was a typo, I've edited the question to fix this, and doesn't  $n\geq |P|+1 \implies n > |P|$?

Comment: Note that $P$ being a path, the number of vertices of $P$ is 1 more than the number of edges of $P$. So when you talk about $|P|$, are you referring to the number of vertices or edges?

Comment: @CalvinLin $|P|$ in this case is the number of vertices, it's the notation that's being used by my instructor. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: If $P$ is the path $x-z-y$ and $Q$ is the path $x-y$, then what is $|P|$ and what is the cycle length of the subgraph induced by P and Q?